# javascript array turns to be undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

Input: `nums = [1,2,3,4]`
Output: `[1,3,6,10]`
Explanation: Running sum is obtained as follows: `[1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4]`.

```
var runningSum = function(nums) {
    const array = new Array (nums.length);
    array[0] = nums[0];
    for( let i=1; i<nums.length; i++){
        array[i] = nums[i] + array[i-1]
    }
};
```

the result turns out to be undefine, I don't know where I did wrong.

Comment: you'll need to `return array`

Answer (score 2):

You have to return the array

so

```
var runningSum = function(nums) {
    const array = new Array (nums.length);
    array[0] = nums[0];
    for( let i=1; i<nums.length; i++){
        array[i] = nums[i] + array[i-1]
    }
    return array;
};
```

instead of

```
var runningSum = function(nums) {
    const array = new Array (nums.length);
    array[0] = nums[0];
    for( let i=1; i<nums.length; i++){
        array[i] = nums[i] + array[i-1]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to solve the problem using recursion.

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const runningSum = (arr, result = [], sum = 0) => {
  if (arr.length === 0) return result;
  const tmp = sum + arr.shift();
  result.push(tmp);
  return runningSum(arr, result, tmp);
};
console.log(runningSum(nums));
```